# Send queries from a secondary PC (SQL Server)

Tags: networking

I have two PC's. One is slow, and has access to a SQL Server via a VPN. The other is fast, but cannot connect to the SQL Server.

Is there a way I can run the queries from the fast PC, and use the slow PC to bridge the connection to the SQL server?

Comment: If the slow PC is the one hosting SQL Server, then running the query on the "fast" PC won't make a difference; it's still the slow PC that's doing all the work

Comment: Thats right, the slow part is not on the query it is afterward because i collect that data and then use it to run a python script, the script it was is slow, so i want to run the script on the fast machine, but that fast pc dont have access to the db so i want to know if there is a way to send the query from the fast pc using the slow pc (the one that have access) as a bridge just to collect the data, important to clarify that the slow pc dont host the db, it is just the pc where is the vpn configured to access the db, the db is on a remote server

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.